# httpd.conf commands to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, filenames, httpd.conf

i use httpd.conf with mod_rewrite to remove file extensions from webpages....

the code i use in httpd.conf is

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       Options +FollowSymLinks
       Options +Indexes
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

this does not work on my external server with .htaccess file, and i have no access to the httpd.conf file....

any ideas how to change the commands so that i can remove all *.html* in urls with a .htaccess instead........

thanks in advance :D

Comment: What URLs did you test with to determine it was not working, and what was the result?

Comment: if that code is in the .htaccess file it just loads error page, 404....

i know that the codes for htaccess and httpd.conf are different and have tried removing line by line, i think the problem is the RewriteRule.... line

Comment: and i have tested nearly all urls for my site with and without the page extension.... with no joy

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if an html version of this file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f [NC]
#then server it
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [NC,L]
```